# WCF Works between different computers, but not on same computer

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication

I have a WCF service, which runs on machine B, and has a client on machine A. This remote connection works perfectly well. I don't have an app.config file, as all the connections are done through code. I'm using Tcp.

The problem arises when I try to run the server and client on the SAME computer. I get the exception: `The Server has rejected the client credentials.` with inner exception: `The logon attempt failed` Why does this fail when I put the client and server on the same computer?

The full service trace is here:

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
<EventID>131075</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
<Level>2</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-04-06T17:24:32.6843236Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{bc168b78-dd81-4f5c-aa30-1cbd991ccec0}" />
<Execution ProcessName="AES_Host.vshost" ProcessID="9096" ThreadID="23" />
<Channel />
<Computer>NYTRD5110B</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Throwing an exception.</Description>
<AppDomain>AES_Host.vshost.exe</AppDomain>
<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>The server has rejected the client credentials.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeAcceptor.OnAcceptUpgrade(Stream stream, SecurityMessageProperty&amp; remoteSecurity)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamSecurityUpgradeAcceptorBase.AcceptUpgrade(Stream stream)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.InitialServerConnectionReader.UpgradeConnection(IConnection connection, StreamUpgradeAcceptor upgradeAcceptor, IDefaultCommunicationTimeouts defaultTimeouts)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader.ServerFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelListener`3.HandleAcceptComplete(TInnerChannel channel)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelListener`3.OnAcceptCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelListener`3.OnAcceptCompletedStatic(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)
at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(Item item, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(T item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionOrientedTransportManager`1.OnHandleServerSessionPreamble(ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader serverSessionPreambleReader, ConnectionDemuxer connectionDemuxer)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionDemuxer.OnSessionPreambleKnown(ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader serverSessionPreambleReader)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader.ContinuePostValidationProcessing()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader.ContinueReading()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader.StartReading(Action`1 viaDelegate, TimeSpan receiveTimeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionDemuxer.OnDuplexConnection(IConnection connection, Action connectionDequeuedCallback, Int64 streamPosition, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionDemuxer.OnConnectionModeKnownCore(ConnectionModeReader modeReader, Boolean isCached)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionModeReader.ReadCallback(Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.TracingConnectionState.ExecuteCallback()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsync(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)
at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.FinishOperationSuccess(SocketError socketError, Int32 bytesTransferred, SocketFlags flags)
at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: The server has rejected the client credentials. ---&gt; System.Security.Authentication.InvalidCredentialException: The server has rejected the client credentials. ---&gt; System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The logon attempt failed
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult, Byte[] message, Exception exception)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextSend(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextSend(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.AuthenticateAsServer(NetworkCredential credential, ProtectionLevel requiredProtectionLevel, TokenImpersonationLevel requiredImpersonationLevel)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeAcceptor.OnAcceptUpgrade(Stream stream, SecurityMessageProperty&amp; remoteSecurity)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.Security.Authentication.InvalidCredentialException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>The server has rejected the client credentials.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult, Byte[] message, Exception exception)
at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
at System.Net.Security.NegoState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextSend(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
at System.Net.Security.NegoState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextSend(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.AuthenticateAsServer(NetworkCredential credential, ProtectionLevel requiredProtectionLevel, TokenImpersonationLevel requiredImpersonationLevel)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeAcceptor.OnAcceptUpgrade(Stream stream, SecurityMessageProperty&amp; remoteSecurity)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.Security.Authentication.InvalidCredentialException: The server has rejected the client credentials. ---&gt; System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The logon attempt failed
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult, Byte[] message, Exception exception)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextSend(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextSend(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.AuthenticateAsServer(NetworkCredential credential, ProtectionLevel requiredProtectionLevel, TokenImpersonationLevel requiredImpersonationLevel)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeAcceptor.OnAcceptUpgrade(Stream stream, SecurityMessageProperty&amp; remoteSecurity)</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>The logon attempt failed</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeAcceptor.OnAcceptUpgrade(Stream stream, SecurityMessageProperty&amp; remoteSecurity)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamSecurityUpgradeAcceptorBase.AcceptUpgrade(Stream stream)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.InitialServerConnectionReader.UpgradeConnection(IConnection connection, StreamUpgradeAcceptor upgradeAcceptor, IDefaultCommunicationTimeouts defaultTimeouts)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader.ServerFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelListener`3.HandleAcceptComplete(TInnerChannel channel)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelListener`3.OnAcceptCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelListener`3.OnAcceptCompletedStatic(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)
at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(Item item, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(T item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionOrientedTransportManager`1.OnHandleServerSessionPreamble(ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader serverSessionPreambleReader, ConnectionDemuxer connectionDemuxer)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionDemuxer.OnSessionPreambleKnown(ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader serverSessionPreambleReader)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader.ContinuePostValidationProcessing()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader.ContinueReading()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader.StartReading(Action`1 viaDelegate, TimeSpan receiveTimeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionDemuxer.OnDuplexConnection(IConnection connection, Action connectionDequeuedCallback, Int64 streamPosition, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionDemuxer.OnConnectionModeKnownCore(ConnectionModeReader modeReader, Boolean isCached)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionModeReader.ReadCallback(Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.TracingConnectionState.ExecuteCallback()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsync(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)
at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.FinishOperationSuccess(SocketError socketError, Int32 bytesTransferred, SocketFlags flags)
at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The logon attempt failed</ExceptionString>
<NativeErrorCode>8009030C</NativeErrorCode>
</InnerException>
</InnerException>
</Exception>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

Comment: Which side fails? The server or the client? I'm guessing you're saying the server is the one that fails yet you didn't move the server?

Comment: Actually, the server refuses the connection before it even gets to my code, so the exception ends up on the client side, and the server continues to run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the service using the internal IP of machine B (192.168...).

If you are still facing issues, it probably means that it's something related to your IIS server authentication configuration, meaning only machine A has rights to connect to your server (i.e. Windows Authentication or specific users).

If it works with the internal IP, then something on machine B is blocking requests coming from localhost (127.0.0.1). You might need to check the advanced firewall settings, or again, the IIS server configurations.